# How to find the input form in the Flutter mobile program structure?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-form-builder

I have a task to solve a bug for an application form update on an application that uses Flutter when it is built. However, this is my first time using Flutter, and the program structure is a bit confusing. Can you tell me the easiest way to find the form structure in a Flutter program?

Comment: it is not confusing, you are just not familiar with it. 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes, this is my first time with flutter. @rashidotm

Answer (score 0):

Start with exploring the screens available in your project to know which screen is being displayed that you need to debug. Then have a look at the widgets which this screen is composed of to point to the one that is causing the bug.

Comment: thanks, i've found the bug. and i try to solve it.

Comment: can you share more details in an answer pls. it will help anyone who comes later.